# Wrong tag name for lxml

Tags: python, lxml

I am using lxml to parse xml I got from amazon product advertisement API.
The tree is parsed as:

```
root=etree.XML(self.sendRequest(parameters))
```

When I use root.tag or root.child.tag, I always get something like:

```
{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05}RequestProcessingTime
```

The link appears in the tag name is actually an attribute of root element:

```
<ItemSearchResponse xmlns="http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2005-10-05">
```

However, it doesn't seem to be correctly parsed.
Is there a way I can remove the annoying {...} from the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part between the braces is the XML namespace, which is read from the `xmlns` attribute of the element.  You can't get rid of it, because this is just how the element tree API which lxml is based on is defined: All tag names are prefixed with their namespace in curly braces.

Some notion of namespacing is mandatory for a well-behaved XML parser to resolve ambiguities, which arise because the same tag name can appear in different namespaces with different meanings, and a single document can contain tags from multiple namespaces.

Your document is parsed correctly, you simply have to consider the namespace in your program.  That's it.